# $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ w/local min @ $x_0$ but $f$ isnt incr before $x_0$ and $f$ isnt decr after$x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

Find $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ has a *strict* local minimum at$x_0$ but $f$ is NOT increasing on any interval ending on $x_0$ and $f$ is NOT decreasing on any interval beginning at $x_0$. No constant functions.

My only thought is $f = x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x}) $

Comment: Hint: Your question (as currently stated) does not require $f$ to be continuous. So try defining it to be one "expression" on the rationals and a different "expression" on the irrationals.